# AngularJS creating scope before service retrieve data from Database

Tags: angularjs, json, web-services, controller

I'm facing a big problem in my application. Here is the deal:

I need to fill a json list with data from the database, create a new childScope and use this json list as a dependency, then I can use this list, creating a bind, without need of calling the parent Scope.

The problem is that my service is just initialized but don't retrieve data to fill the list, then the scope is created right after the initialization and as my list is still null, it sends a null list as dependency.

Only after the new scope is created my service retrieve data form database an fill the json list.

Is there anyway to make services be executed and retrieve data before the creation of childScopes?

Here is an exempla os the code:

```
myModule.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',  function($scope) {

// code here...

$scope.init() {
        ResourceService.load($scope.myServicePath, ResourceService.list).get({}, function(response) {
        $scope.myList = response.data;
    });
}
init();

$scope.injectControllers = function(){

    $scope.newScope = $scope.$new();
        $controller('myOtherCtrl',
            {$scope : $scope.newScope,
            myList : $scope.myList});
    }
injectControllers(); 

}]);
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do but I think that you need to read about .config and .run blocks.

Comment: If you are using ui-router or ngRoute you can fetch the data in a resolve to the current state. Then the data will be fetched and injected before controller instantiation.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just wait for the service to return before you make your call to `injectControllers()`? That is, put `injectControllers()` on the very next line after `$scope.myList = response.data;`?